# Inner Join Insert

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables `Users` and `UserGroups`.

I now need to get `UsergroupID` to use in `Users`. So I am trying an Inner Join to insert the `UsergroupID` to `Users`. I don't receive an error, but at the same time its not inserting anything.

```sql
INSERT INTO Users.UserName,Users.Password, Users.UserGroupID,UserGroups.UserGroupName 
FROM Users INNER JOIN (SELECT UserGroupID, UserGroupName FROM UserGroups) UserGroups on Users.UserGroupID = '" & Me.cmbUserGroup & "'"
```

So I expect the new users to have a UserGroupID That has been selected.

```
UserID  UserName    Password    UserGroupID
1       JvN88       438         1
2       Test        12231       1
3       New         11111       1
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `insert` SQL statement is incorrect: you are missing the target table into which the records should be inserted.

The syntax should follow either:

```
insert into <table> ( <columns> ) select <columns> from <table/query> ...
```

Or:

```
insert into <table> ( <columns> ) values ( <values> )
```

The `( <columns> )` argument can be omitted if all table columns are to be populated.